# Unexpected output from Properties.contains()

Tags: java, file, properties

I am getting an unexpected output from `Properties.contains()`...

This is my code...

```
File file = new File("C:\\ravi\\non-existing.no");
Properties pro = System.getProperties();
pro.put("file", file);
System.out.println(pro.contains(file)); //PRINTS TRUE , AS EXPECTED

File file2 = file;
System.out.println(pro.contains(file2)); //PRINTS TRUE , AS EXPECTED

File file3 = new File("C:\\ravi\\non-existing.no");
System.out.println(pro.contains(file3)); //EXPECTED FALSE , BUT PRINTS TRUE

File file4 = new File("C:\\ravi\\non.no");
System.out.println(pro.contains(file4)); //PRINTS FALSE , AS EXPECTED
```

I am expecting the `Properties` to check for the existance of the `File`, however this doesn't seem to work. Could someone please help me explain why `file3` doesn't work as I expect.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve here? Please be more specific.

Comment: i would like to know the reason why 10th line of code give output as false.

Comment: File file3 = new File("C:\\ravi\\non-existing.no"); says nothing about the existence of the file. Whether or not the file exists, it performs just like the other statements

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think your problem lies here :

```
 pro.put("file", file);
```

From the Java docs:

*Because Properties inherits from Hashtable, the put and putAll methods can be applied to a Properties object. Their use is strongly discouraged as they allow the caller to insert entries whose keys or values are not Strings. The setProperty method should be used instead.*

And when you call `contains()` on it, according to the Java docs:

*returns true if and only if some key maps to the value argument in this hashtable as determined by the equals method; false otherwise.*

You see your problem now?

To clarify further:

When you do :`System.out.println(pro.contains(file3));` you end up doing `file.equals(file3)` , hence `true`.

And when you do :`System.out.println(pro.contains(file4));` you end up doing `file.equals(file4)` , hence `false`.

Answer (score 6):

This is as expected, since `Properties#contains()` will call `File#equals()`, which in turn delegates to `fs#compare()` which compares two abstract pathnames lexicographically. I.e, two files pointing to the same path will indeed be equal.

Comment: +1. Since `file.equals(file3)` how would one expect otherwise? But *don't put non-String things into a Properties object* in the first place!

Answer (score 1):

See Property class definition its

```
public class Properties extends Hashtable<Object,Object>
```

And `contains` is method of [Hashtable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Hashtable.html) which states -

```
    Tests if some key maps into the specified value in this hashtable.
    This operation is more expensive than the containsKey method.
    Note that this method is identical in functionality to containsValue,
   (which is part of the Map interface in the collections framework).
```

*And it returns true if and only if some key maps to the value argument in this hashtable as determined by the equals method; false otherwise.*